# How to @Inject JsonWebToken when having both quarkus-smallrye-jwt and quarkus-oidc in Quarkus application

Tags: jwt, single-sign-on, quarkus, smallrye, quarkus-oidc

In my Quarkus application, there are two types of authentication:

1. Locally => I'm using `quarkus-smallrye-jwt` to authen local.

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
>   <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. SSO via Keycloak => I'm using `quarkus-oidc` to authen with Keycloak

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
>   <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

For the controllers are marked `@Authenticated` then `@Inject JsonWebToken` it will return `DefaultJWTCallerPrincipal`(proxy `OidcJsonWebTokenProducer`).

```
@Authenticated
@Path("/api/v1/oidc")
public class OIDCController {

    @Inject
    @IdToken
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<Response> login() {
        ...
    }
}
```

For normal controllers used local JWT then `@Inject JsonWebToken` it will return `NullJsonWebToken`(proxy `OidcJsonWebTokenProducer`) => my expected is that it will return `DefaultJWTCallerPrincipal`(proxy `JwtPrincipalProducer`) instead.

```
@Path("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<Response> login() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, do we have any ways to configure this one?

Comment: Answered for this one  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/33976#discussioncomment-6153676